# 404 errors with .htaccess and php files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mamp, server

I keep getting 404 errors when I type.

localhost/shirt.php?id= followed by an number from an array I created

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shirts/$ /shirts/shirts.php
RewriteRule ^shirts/([0-9]+)/$ /shirts/shirt.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^receipt.php$ /receipt/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact.php$ /contact/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^shirts.php$ /shirts/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^shirt.php$ /shirt/%1/? [R=301]
```

Using MAMP with Chrome and I've cleared my cache multiple times

Comment: Ah, the joys of `301 Moved Permanently`! You will have fun until you really close the browser and re-open it (and even then still maybe). While developing you should never use `[R=301]`, because browsers cache that redirect very aggressively.

Comment: is this what you want to happen: `localhost/shirt.php?id=` requested in browser, `RewriteRule ^shirt.php$ /shirt/%1/? [R=301]` gets matched and `301`'ed to  `RewriteRule ^shirts/([0-9]+)/$ /shirts/shirt.php?id=$1` ? if so, you dont have a rule to catch the new URL

Comment: what are you trying to do? What URLs do you want to show in browser and what should be internal URL?

Comment: @Boldewyn just shut down the chrome reopended yet another 404

Comment: @anubhava I'm aiming for something like this http://localhost/shirt/101/ but on my localserver it'll look like local/shirt.php?id= anything from the array

Comment: @MichaelColeman how do I go about writing a rule to catch the new url. Still kinda new to .htaccess and php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after staying up for a couple more hours I've figured it out

Adding a Trailing Slash to the end of the url

```
RewriteRule ^(contact/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /$1/ [R=301]
```

Rewriting the Rules with Query Strings

```
RewriteRule ^contact/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /contact/index.php?status=thanks
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^status=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /contact/%1/? [R=301]
```

This is what worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+shirt\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ shirt/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^shirt/(\d+)/?$ shirt.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Make sure you don't have any other rule when you test this.

Comment: didn't work for me, but I fiddle with it and now it works? Just had to rewrite everything step by step thanks

Comment: Glad to know it worked out. If you think this answer was helpful to you then you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.